# Error handling for this javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to build in error handling for this piece of javascript so that if #next doesnt exist that it will do something else.  Currently when it doesnt exist it just gives me an undefined in the url or an error page.  Please let me know what i can do here.  thanks

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
  var leva = $('#next').attr("href");
  var prava = $('#prev').attr("href");

  $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped right!");-->
    location.href=prava;
  });                       
  $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped left!");-->
    location.href=leva;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can check `$('#next').length` to see if any elements were selected. Or just check if `leva` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Chad do you have a recommendation for how to do this?

Comment: `if(leva) { location.href=leva } else { /* do something else */ }`

Comment: Thanks @Chad if you want to put it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `$('#next').length` to see if any elements were selected. Or just check if `leva` is `undefined`.

Something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
  var leva = $('#next').attr("href");
  var prava = $('#prev').attr("href");

  $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped right!");-->
    location.href=prava;
  });                       
  $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped left!");-->
    if(leva) {
      location.href=leva;
    } else {
      // Some other action
    }
  });
});
</script>
```